# Why my data-binding doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, sharepoint-2010

I'm developing a SharePoint 2010 Web Part. I would use knockout framework for data-binding.

I have one ascx with this code:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label id="lblLastMaintenanceDate">Data ultima manuntenzione:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="lastMaintenanceDate" data-bind="text: lastMaintenanceDate"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label id="lblMaintenanceDescription">Descrizione manuntenzione:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="MaintenanceDescription" data-bind="text: maintenanceDescription"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label id="lblConcept">Concept:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="Concept" data-bind="text: concept"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Inside document.ready() I wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(ShopViewModel);
});
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
var ShopViewModel = {
lastMaintenanceDate : ko.observable(),
maintenanceDescription : ko.observable(),
concept : ko.observable(),

GetShopDetail : function (val1) {

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../_layouts/MyProject/MasterPage.aspx/GetDetails?par1=" + val1,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var oJson = eval("(" + result['d'] + ")");
            if (oJson.Success) {
                var result = oJson.Data;
                if (result) {
                    this.lastMaintenanceDate = String(result.LastMaintenanceDate);
                    this.maintenanceDescription = String(result.MaintenanceDescription);
                    this.concept = String(result.SyConceptId);
                }
            }
            else {
                WriteToConsole(oJson.Error);
                customAlert(oJson.Error, "Error");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

And I call GetShopDetail function with this code:

```
ShopViewModel.GetShopDetail(val1);
```

My problem is that data-binding doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Because `this` within your ajax callback is not your viewmodel. If you want it to be, use `bind`
2. Because you're replacing your observables with raw properties. Instead, set the value of the observable

So:

```
    success: function (result) {
        var oJson = eval("(" + result['d'] + ")");
        if (oJson.Success) {
            var result = oJson.Data;
            if (result) {
                // ************** Change on next three lines
                this.lastMaintenanceDate(String(result.LastMaintenanceDate));
                this.maintenanceDescription(String(result.MaintenanceDescription));
                this.concept(String(result.SyConceptId));
            }
        }
        else {
            WriteToConsole(oJson.Error);
            customAlert(oJson.Error, "Error");
        }
    }.bind(this)     // <===== Change here
```

Re #2, I suggest working through the [Knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), as this is one of the most fundamental aspects of KO.

---

Side note: Don't use `eval` to parse JSON. Use `JSON.parse` to parse JSON. Or `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: Hi Crowder, You save me a lot of time. Thanks!